# Problems running Cython

Tags: c++, python, cython

I'm trying to run cython with Python2.7 installed using OSX running Mountain Lion but I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/cython", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2603, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 666, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req)  # XXX put more info here
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: Cython==0.17
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: ...did you `easy_install cython`?

Comment: Notice the path names.  It looks like `/usr/local/bin/cython` is attempting to use `python2.6`.  This is a bit of a long shot but try this: `python2.7 /usr/local/bin/cython`

Answer (score 0):

Probably what happened is that you installed cython with one version of python and are trying to run it with another.  Rather than doing the standard

```
python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

Try just switching to root and both building and installing using an explicit version of python:

```
sudo su
/usr/bin/python setup.py build
/usr/bin/python setup.py install
```

(Note that this all assumes that you're installing from a source tarball).